# CUDA __device__ Unresolved extern function

Tags: c++, c, cuda, linker-errors

I am trying to understand how to decouple CUDA `__device__` codes in separate header files.

I have three files.

**File: 1: int2.cuh**

```
#ifndef INT2_H_
#define INT2_H_

#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

__global__ void kernel();
__device__ int k2(int k);

int launchKernel(int dim);

#endif /* INT2_H_ */
```

**File 2: int2.cu**

```
#include "int2.cuh"
#include "cstdio"

__global__ void kernel() {
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    printf("%d\n", k2(tid));
}

__device__ int k2(int i) {
    return i * i;
}

int launchKernel(int dim) {
    kernel<<<1, dim>>>();
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

**File 3: CUDASample.cu**

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "int2.cuh"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

static const int WORK_SIZE = 256;

__global__ void sampleCuda() {
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
//    printf("%d\n", k2(tid)); //Can not call k2
    printf("%d\n", tid * tid);
}

int main(void) {

    int var;
    var = launchKernel(16);

    kernel<<<1, 16>>>();
    cudaDeviceReset();

    sampleCuda<<<1, 16>>>();
    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine. I can call the `sampleCuda()` kernel (in same file), call the C function `launchKernel()` (in other file), and call `kernel()` directly (in other file).

However, I get the following error when calling the `__device__` function from the `sampleCuda()` kernel. The same function is callable in `kernel()`.

```
10:58:11 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project CUDASample ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/CUDASample.cu
Invoking: NVCC Compiler
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.5/bin/nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20  -odir "src" -M -o "src/CUDASample.d" "../src/CUDASample.cu"
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.5/bin/nvcc -G -g -O0 --compile --relocatable-device-code=false -gencode arch=compute_20,code=compute_20 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20  -x cu -o  "src/CUDASample.o" "../src/CUDASample.cu"
../src/CUDASample.cu(18): warning: variable "var" was set but never used

../src/CUDASample.cu(8): warning: variable "WORK_SIZE" was declared but never referenced

../src/CUDASample.cu(18): warning: variable "var" was set but never used

../src/CUDASample.cu(8): warning: variable "WORK_SIZE" was declared but never referenced

ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_Z2k2i'
make: *** [src/CUDASample.o] Error 255

10:58:14 Build Finished (took 2s.388ms)
```

How do I call the `__device__` function from the `sampleCuda()` kernel ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is that you defined a `__device__` function in separate compilation unit from `__global__` that calls it. You need to either explicitely enable *relocatable device code* mode by adding `-dc` flag or move your definition to the same unit.

From [`nvcc`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#axzz3dtmHNH7F) documentation:

> `--device-c|-dc` Compile each .c/.cc/.cpp/.cxx/.cu input file into an object file that contains relocatable device code. It is equivalent to
>   `--relocatable-device-code`=true `--compile`.

See [Separate Compilation and Linking of CUDA C++ Device Code](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/) for more information.

Comment: I had been using Nsight for the building process. --relocatable-device-code=false was set there. I modified it, but it does not work immediately. I will do few more experiments.

Comment: nsight EE has a project option that you can use to select a "separate compilation" project type when you are creating the project.  If you create the project this way, it is probably easier than modifying the makefile script directly.

Comment: Yep, I just found that.