# How do I compile a CUDA shared library that depends on c++ object files?

Tags: c++, makefile, cuda

I am writing a c++/CUDA library with multiple calls to kernels.

EDIT: I think the original post was a little long, so I have created a better example. Original post below.

Here is the project simplified to a minimal example. It will not compile, and gives the following error:

```
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -x cu -c -dc -o myclass.o myclass.cpp
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC --lib myclass.o kernel.cu -o libhelpme.a -I.
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_ZN7myclassC1Ei'
makefile:8: recipe for target 'lib' failed
make: *** [lib] Error 255
```

All documentation on this topic points towards compiling an executable or an object file; I want to do neither of these, rather a static library specifically. How do I do this?

The code:

`makefile`

```
program: class lib
    nvcc -o program main.cc -I. -L. -lhelpme

class:
    nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -x cu -c -dc -o myclass.o myclass.cpp

lib: class
    nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC --lib myclass.o kernel.cu -o libhelpme.a -I.

clean:
    rm *.o *.a program
```

`main.cc`

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "kernel.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    wrapper();
    return 0;
}
```

`myclass.h`

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define COMMON __host__ __device__
#else
#define COMMON
#endif
#ifndef M
#define M
class myclass
{
    public:
        int x;
        COMMON myclass(int y);
        COMMON void increment();
};
#endif
```

`myclass.cpp`

```
#include "myclass.h"
#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define COMMON __host__ __device__
#else
#define COMMON
#endif
COMMON myclass::myclass(int y)
{
    x = y;
}
COMMON void myclass::increment()
{
    x += 1;
}
```

`kernel.h`

```
extern void wrapper();
```

`kernel.cu`

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "myclass.h"

class myotherclass
{
    public:
        int x;
        COMMON myotherclass(int y) {x = y;}
        COMMON void decrement() {x -= 1;}
};

__global__ void dokernel()
{
    myotherclass p(8); //This compiles just fine.
    myclass q(7); //This will not compile
}

void wrapper()
{
    std::cout << "hello from wrapper\n";
    myclass q(1);
    myotherclass s(4);
    std::cout << "x = " << s.x << "\n";
    s.decrement();
    std::cout << "x = " << s.x << "\n";
    dokernel<<<1,1>>>();

}
```

I am slowly becoming convinced that this is impossible...

ORIGINAL POST: I have a number of c++ source/header files, e.g. `vec.cpp` and `vec.h` being compiled to object files, e.g. `vec.o`

Here is an example: `vec.h`

```
class vec
{
    public:
        realnum x,y,z;
        __host__ __device__ vec(float _x, float _y, float _z);
}
```

`vec.cpp`

```
__host__ __device__ vec::vec(float _x, float _y, float _z) {x = _x; y = _y; z = _z;}
```

Here is my full makefile (still in the making):

```
CC=nvcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -O3

HOME_DIR = $(shell pwd)

SRC_DIR := ${HOME_DIR}/../src
OBJ_DIR := ${HOME_DIR}/../lib
LIB_DIR := ${HOME_DIR}/../lib
KER_DIR := ${HOME_DIR}/../kernel
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

LPROPS := -L${LIB_DIR} -lcuprops
LMAIN := -L${LIB_DIR} -lsharc
LRDR := -L${LIB_DIR} -lcurdr

INCL_PROPS := -I${SRC_DIR} -I${KER_DIR}

program: $(LIB_DIR)/libcurdr.so ${LIB_DIR}/libsharc.so $(LIB_DIR)/libcuprops.so $(OBJ_FILES)
    ${CC} -o $@ main.cc -I${SRC_DIR} ${LPROPS} ${LMAIN} ${LRDR}

${LIB_DIR}/libsharc.so: $(OBJ_FILES) $(LIB_DIR)/libcuprops.so
    ${CC} -Xcompiler -fPIC --shared  ${OBJ_FILES} -o $(LIB_DIR)/libsharc.so ${INCL_PROPS}

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    ${CC} -Xcompiler -fPIC -dc -o $@ $< ${INCL_PROPS}

$(LIB_DIR)/libcuprops.so:
    ${CC} -Xcompiler -fPIC --shared -o $(LIB_DIR)/libcuprops.so ${KER_DIR}/nvidia_properties.cu ${INCL_PROPS}

$(LIB_DIR)/libcurdr.so: $(OBJ_FILES)
    ${CC} -Xcompiler -fPIC --shared ${OBJ_FILES} ${KER_DIR}/gpu_rdr.cu -o $(LIB_DIR)/libcurdr.so ${INCL_PROPS}

clean:
    rm ${LIB_DIR}/*
```

When I `make` I get the following:

```
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_ZN3vecC1Eddd'
```

I have a kernel where I try to initialize a vector:

```
__global__ void SOME_KERNEL()
{
    int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (row < dev_height && col < dev_width)
    {
        vec t(0,0,0); //Compiles nicely when I comment out this line!
    }
}
```

I have read about [separate compiling and linking](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/) where it is claimed that the typical project architecture (that I believe that I am using) is compatible with separate compiling and linking via the following:

```
objects = main.o particle.o v3.o

all: $(objects)
    nvcc -arch=sm_20 $(objects) -o app

%.o: %.cpp
    nvcc -x cu -arch=sm_20 -I. -dc $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o app
```

Note the use of the "-dc" flag, which is consistent with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006581/cuda-device-unresolved-extern-function) answer.

At this point I have tried so many things that I am completely lost. So, how can I compile this project?

In the case that it is helpful, here is the full output from make:

```
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -dc -o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/mat33.o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../src/mat33.cpp -I/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../src -I/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../kernel
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -dc -o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/vec.o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../src/vec.cpp -I/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../src -I/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../kernel
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -dc -o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/sharc.o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../src/sharc.cpp -I/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../src -I/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../kernel
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -dc -o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/boundingbox.o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../src/boundingbox.cpp -I/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../src -I/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../kernel
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC --shared /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/mat33.o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/vec.o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/sharc.o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/boundingbox.o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../kernel/gpu_rdr.cu -o /home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/libcurdr.so -I/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../src -I/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../kernel
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_ZN3vecC1Eddd'
makefile:32: recipe for target '/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/libcurdr.so' failed
make: *** [/home/wvn/dirs/projects/sharc/build/../lib/libcurdr.so] Error 255
```

Comment: one problem you have is that you have CUDA code in filenames ending in `.cpp`  That won't work unless you specify `-x cu` when compiling.  So add `-x cu` to the makefile line that is compiling your individual .cpp objects: `${CC} -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC -dc -o $@ $< ${INCL_PROPS}`.  I'm not saying that will fix everything, but it is necessary based on your current project structure.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I think you can also use #ifdef __CUDACC__ to do that, and define some macro "#define COMMON __host__ __device__" if __CUDACC__ is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the UPDATED post, not the ORIGINAL post.

As indicated in the comments, one of the things needed was to add `-x cu` when you are compiling files that end in `.cpp` but contain CUDA constructs or device code.  You've already added that in the proper place.

Your discussion around your `COMMON` macro has no bearing on this.  They serve separate purposes.  The macro is not a substitute for `-x cu`.

The other missing thing is that you need to instruct `nvcc` at the static library generation point that relocatable device code and device linking is needed.  You do this by adding `-rdc=true` to the compile command line.  Your `Makefile` could be modified like this:

```
lib: class
    nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -rdc=true --lib myclass.o kernel.cu -o libhelpme.a -I.
```

This is needed because you have device code in one compilation unit (`kernel.cu`) that is calling device code in another compilation unit (`myclass.cpp`).

With that change, your UPDATED post/project compiles without issue for me and also runs without error.

```
$ make clean
rm *.o *.a program
$ make
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -x cu -c -dc -o myclass.o myclass.cpp
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -rdc=true --lib myclass.o kernel.cu -o libhelpme.a -I.
nvcc -o program main.cc -I. -L. -lhelpme
$ cuda-memcheck ./program
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
hello world
hello from wrapper
x = 4
x = 3
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```